# Качественное отображение изображений в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Как в WPF отобразить изображение качественно?
Тестировал много изображений в различных форматах.
Например изображение с разрешением 8196x8196 в PNG формате,
но при добавлении в окно оно начинает отображаться пикселями:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот изображение в оригинальном средстве просмотра фотографий:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вероятно использовать векторную графику.

Comment: @Сергей: все иконки рисуются в векторе, а в какой формат лучше экспортировать, чтобы в wpf было корректное отображение?

Comment: Создаете файл `SVG` формата, в нем будет некий код, копируете его и вставляете в элемент `<Path Data="__" />`. В итоге получаете качественное векторное изображение. Ну а что касается именно пиксельности изображения, то попробуйте поиграться с `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode` (вроде оно). Ну а также есть [вот такая](https://habrahabr.ru/post/216833/) статья, почитайте, полезный материал.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуйте выставить параметр [RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions.bitmapscalingmode(v=vs.110).aspx) в значение HighQuality.

```
<Image RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"
   Source="/someImage.png"
   Width="100"
   Height="100" />
```

Comment: спасибо большое!